# Django admin fails with bootstraps "danger" class?

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-1.11

In my django admin, error messages (using the messages framework) are created with `danger` class. However the message looks green with an approval sign over it:

[image]

When looking into `admin/css/base.css`, it looks like the error class is `error` and not `danger`.

Why does it show as `danger`? How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no message level called *danger*. What you could use is either `warning` or `error`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/#message-levels

```
DEBUG   Development-related messages that will be ignored (or removed) 
        in a production deployment
INFO    Informational messages for the user
SUCCESS An action was successful, e.g. “Your profile was updated successfully”
WARNING A failure did not occur but may be imminent
ERROR   An action was not successful or some other failure occurred
```

Comment: Sorry. Thank you. Got mixed up with bootstrap's `danger`.